# Drag uiview to push viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I would like to push a view B to the navigationcontroller dragging a uiview inserted in view A! Like Whatsapp do to show single message delivery info! Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
//use swipe gesture recognizer

   UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer   alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeHandler:)];
   [gestureRecognizer setDirection:(UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)];
   [self.view addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];


-(void)swipeHandler:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
NSLog(@"Swipe received.");
}
```

Comment: Yes but how can i push the view controller? If i push in a normal way it start ios animation to open view and i lose the drag movement!